# Not able to set color through custom TextView android

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, android-custom-view, custom-component

Hi 
 I had requirement to implement a custom textview to be used across all modules in my app. 
 I am facing issues while setting color through custom textview. 
 The color is not set through custom TextView 
 Please find my implementation and help me in resolving this issue

attrs.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <declare-styleable name="CustomFontTextView">
            <attr name="textColor"></attr>
        </declare-styleable>
         <attr name="textColor" format="enum">
        <enum name="Regular_Color" value="1"/>
      
    </attr>
</resources>
```

strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestApp</string>
    <string name="Regular_Color">colorNormal</string>
</resources>
```

colors.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
    <color name = "colorNormal">#00FF00</color>
</resources>
```

CustomTextView:

```
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    class CustomFontTextView   @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
        defStyle: Int = 0,
        defStyleRes: Int = 0
    ) : AppCompatTextView(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        var customFont: String? = null
    
        init {
                attrs?.let {
val a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.CustomFontTextView
        )
                            setColor(a,context, attrs);
                 }
        }

 @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private fun setColor(typedArray: TypedArray, context: Context,
                         attrs: AttributeSet){

        val cf = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomFontTextView_textColor, 0)
        var textViewColor = 0
        textViewColor = when(cf){
            1 -> R.color.colorNormal
            else->R.string.Regular_Color
        }
     
        this.setTextColor(textViewColor)
        invalidate()
        requestLayout()
     

    }
}
```

When the app is run the color is not set actually its supposed to set green color.

My layout is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.android.dynamicfeaturemodulesample.UI.CustomFontTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:textColor="Regular_Color"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: You are passing String "Regular_Color" and trying to get Int from attributes. Why don't you use android:textColor="@color/colorNormal"?

Comment: I want to use it from custom component. My custom component should have all the attributes code....